# Why does `startx /usr/bin/unity` not load my desktop settings?

Tags: unity, xorg, settings, tty

I am trying to open a second X session with unity on display :1.

For this to achieve I open another terminal (e.g. tty 6) with `Ctrl` + `Alt` +`6` and login as the user whose desktop session I want to start. When I start the X session with unity as a client on display :1, unity loads but does not adhere to my desktop settings.

This is how I start the session:

```
$ startx /usr/bin/unity -- :1
```

This does not work properly:

- Startup applications don't start.
- dconf settings are not read (e.g. `org.gnome.desktop.interface.text-scaling-factor`)
- The language of the desktop is not correct (This user's desktop should be English while my main user has a German desktop).
- ... maybe other stuff I did not notice.

I also tried to start X with

```
$ startx -- :1
```

This shows the correct desktop wallpaper but does not show anything else (no xterm, no panels, no dash, ...). But `Ctrl` + `Alt` +`T` opens a decorated terminal and I can start `unity`. That loads unity with almost everything I need. But the language still is German.

I also tried appending `unity` to `~/.xinitrc` but that did not change anything.

Can someone point out my mistakes? An optimal solution for me would be to being able to start a second unity session with `startx -- :1`.

Comment: Oh. By accident I just stumbled upon the solution for my problem: Obviously I just need to use the user switcher in the panel and lightdm opens the session of the second user on display :1. This does not answer my questions but solves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to manually start an xsession like that, you should rather do something like `gnome-session --session=ubuntu`. gnome-session will load required components such as gnome-settings-daemon which in turn will configure your stuff.

Sessions are stored in /usr/share/gnome-session/sessions/. You'll see things like "gnome.session" and "ubuntu.session". You use the file name without the ".session" extension in the --session parameter.

Likewise, if you want to properly shut down your desktop session, you can kill that instance of gnome-session.

Comment: Thanks. Where would I do that? In the tty? Can I pass an argument which display should be used? I can't find how to do that.

If I run `startx -- :1` first, open a terminal and start `gnome-session --session=ubuntu` I get an error message: "Failed to aquire org.gnome.SessionManager".

Answer (score 0):

I'm using following method for tty:

```
cp ~/.xinitrc ~/.xinitrc.old # if they exist
echo "exec unity" > ~/.xinitrc  # or "exec gnome-session --session=ubuntu"
sudo startx -- :1
```

And i have full-featured session Desktop Environment. 
BUT, if you go to another tty, session will be broken.