# How do I boot directly to tty1 in ubuntu?

Tags: boot, 16.04

I want to make sure when my pc starts up, it boots into tty1, instead of tty7. And also, in case I need it, I should also be able to switch to the graphical desktop using ctrl +alt+f7 in case I need it. 
How do I do that?

Comment: I'd just press CTRL+ALT+1 when it starts up.  Interested to see the answers here.

Comment: I want it to boot to the tty1 automatically. @earthmeLon

Comment: Remove your Display manager. Then to boot inti gui do `startx` from ttyX. But for that you need a `.xinitrc` file in your `$HOME`.

Comment: @Raphael far too radical.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I set my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS to boot to console without GUI?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/174312/how-can-i-set-my-ubuntu-12-04-lts-to-boot-to-console-without-gui) and possible duplicate of  [How to boot to Ubuntu desktop from the console](http://askubuntu.com/questions/805536/how-to-boot-to-ubuntu-desktop-from-the-console)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Find `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in `/etc/default/grub` (with a `sudo nano /etc/default/grub` and change it to ...

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="text"
```

and update grub with ...

```
sudo update-grub
```

Tell systemd to not load the desktop with ...

```
sudo systemctl enable multi-user.target --force
sudo systemctl set-default multi-user.target
```

And the initial boot will end up on a tty. By default it will be tty1. You can still go to the desktop by using the command `startx` on commandline.

> I should also be able to switch to the graphical desktop using ctrl +alt+f7 in case I need it.

You will need to issue the `sudo systemctl start lightdm` command before using control+alt+f7. Probably impossible to get around that: if a desktop is loaded during boot it will take precedence.

Comment: It seems like with `startx` all I find is my desktop background with an 'X' as my pointer. No launcher, no icons. @Rinzwind

Comment: do  any of these work: http://askubuntu.com/questions/320042/why-does-startx-usr-bin-unity-not-load-my-desktop-settings ?

Comment: I am not using `startx`, but instead figured out I needed to start the lightdm. So I did this- `systemctl sudo start lightdm` and works fine now.

Comment: check! added it.

Comment: I did a minimal install of ubuntu server 16.04.2 and for some reason it had `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="splash quiet"` as the default.  Changed that to `text` as suggested and updated grub and now I'm booting to `tty1`.  Thanks.